# Redirect URL on form

Tags: kentico

I am trying to redirect a Kentico form based on whether a checkbox is selected. I tried adding a macro in the URL direct property using the checkbox id generated by Kentico and the element name but it doesn't seem to work.

Anyone have any examples?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

What macro are you trying to use?  I just tested (with a textbox field not a checkbox field) and it worked:

```
/home?{%emailinput.value != "" ? "notEmpty" : "empty"%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a bit field "mycheck" and your form called "mytestform"

If you put the following macro in Forms\mytestform\General\After the form is submitted-> Redirect to URL:

```
/{%CMSContext.Current.SiteObjects.Forms.mytestform.Items.LastItem.mycheck? "mytest2/" : "mytest1/" #%}
```

Based on mycheck value a user will either redirected to /mytest2/ or /mytest1/

Comment: There is no need for such a long macro. You can use just {% mycheck?: %}. Moreover lastitem doesnt have to be the item you want.